# How to define the lua module path in nifi Processor ExecuteScript?

Tags: module, lua, apache-nifi

I am new to Lua.

Several days ago, I complished using python in ExecuteScript of NIFI. I set Python Module path to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Everything goes well.

But doing the same thing with Lua is so difficult for me. Always Error of cannot find the Module!!!

I use `Luarock` to install modules.

Could you please tell me how to set the lua module path or some useful infomation about it?

Here comes some info of my Luarocks setting:

```
lbh@es-2:~/install/nifi-1.1.1/lua_modules$ luarocks list

Installed rocks:

----------------

lua-cjson
   2.1.0-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks

luasocket
   3.0rc1-2 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks

redis-lua
   2.0.4-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

An example of lua-cjson.

```
lbh@es-2:~/install/nifi-1.1.1/lua_modules$ luarocks show lua-cjson

lua-cjson 2.1.0-1 - A fast JSON encoding/parsing module

The Lua CJSON module provides JSON support for Lua. It features: - Fast,
standards compliant encoding/parsing routines - Full support for JSON with
UTF-8, including decoding surrogate pairs - Optional run-time support for
common exceptions to the JSON specification (infinity, NaN,..) - No
dependencies on other libraries

License:    MIT
Homepage:   http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson.php
Installed in:   /usr/local

Modules:
    cjson
    lua2json
    json2lua
    cjson.util
```

Directory info of `/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks`

```
lbh@es-2:~/install/nifi-1.1.1/lua_modules$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 17 11:13 lua-cjson
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 17 11:18 luasocket
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3653 Mar 17 11:18 manifest
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Mar 17 11:18 redis-lua
```